# Dead Raspberry Pi 4? How to see boot log when it doesn't boot

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I have a Pi4 with a known good SD card but it doesn't boot.  Red and green light comes on, then the green goes away and it does nothing. It was working fine until recently then just died. This is a new SD card image and it did not help.

If I turn it on without the SD card in I do get the boot screen:
[image: Pi Boot Screen 1]

[image: Pi boot screen 2]

If I then put an SD card in or a USB stick with Raspbian OS on it the screen scrolls something then it goes black.

[image: Pi Before Death]

I tried going into the config.txt file on the boot partition and setting safe HDMI modes and things like that and i get nothing.

Is there any way I can get a text log of what is going on before it dies?  I want to keep seeing the text of what is going on and what is failing in the boot process but the screen goes completely black.  I might have the serial cable for Pi somewhere if that would help.

Answer (score 0):

The "Install an OS on this Raspberry Pi" screen happens when an SD card isn't detected or you didn't put one back in. You can take a video of what is happening and pause the video before the screen goes black. You can also capture the screen with a UART cable. I notice that the black screen (with the boot errors) says that it doesn't detect an SD card after the board number. If your card is formatted, you can move the contents to a new card. It might  be a SD card problem because the green light indicates that you have a successful SD card connection. If it goes away when the boot log shows up, then it's an SD card problem. Like I said before, if your SD card is formatted, then you can copy the contents to a new card, but if your card is preloaded or not formatted, then there's no luck.